# Ошибка при работе с ф-ей fetch в PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

Вот код:

```
$ql = $sql->fetch("*","test","'text'='text'");
```

Вот ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in X:\home\game\www\index.php on line 3

Comment: Приведите код метода fetch класса sql

Answer (score 1):

Ну, в принципе ясно написано. В 3-й строке находится **не объект**. А по какой причине там не объект приведенный кусок кода ничего не скажет.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у Вас свой класс с этой функцией.
Поэтому Вам вряд ли кто - то, что - то скажет по этому поводу.
Могу сказать что стандартной функции fetch() в PHP нету.